# breadcrumbs on one line, resizing the page should only hide it, not break it into many lines

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I'd like my breadcrumbs to stand on the initial line whatever the page width is, so I thought of this http://fiddle.jshell.net/G6mQb/1/

It does actually exactly what we want, however we can't set the ul width, and without it, it doesn't work. http://fiddle.jshell.net/G6mQb/

Another thing, I was told that no js would be used to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` on the li's, you can use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent line breaks. I don't see any reason to use floats in this case.

Read about white-space here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hb3LJ/